# Javamail api did not send any mail

Tags: android, jakarta-mail

I am using [the link](http://androidcodeexamples.blogspot.in/2012/05/android-send-email-via-gmail-actually.html) for sending  html email from my android application. But it does not send any mail.
Here i have an html page saved in sdcard and it  is used as body content of html .What is the problem?How can i solve this?

Comment: No.i did not get any response.

Comment: Then what does your logcat says? have u checked it? have u  added these 1) activation.jar
2) additionnal.jar
3) mail.jar in to ur project build path and INTERNET PERMISSION in your manifest?(in the mentioned link I have seen these)

Comment: Yes.I have.when click on send button it does not show any response.

Comment: Check your log on the button click to know whats the exact problem and post ur logcat messages , so that people can help you!!!

Comment: is it possible to send html content using javamail api without using Html.fromHtml()

Comment: YES, you can, I have already mentioned you to post the logcat messages but u didn"t, ok then Instead of using text/plain , try to use text/html  in this line  DataHandler handler = new DataHandler(new ByteArrayDataSource(
body.getBytes(), "text/plain")); of gmailsender.java and check wether its working or not

Comment: it does not show any exception in the logcat output.I am tried using text/html .But no result

Comment: 09-19 16:17:50.147: E/GMailSender(23581): Exception = null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public void sendMail(){
                String tempAddress = emailTo.getText().toString();
                String[] toArr = tempAddress.split(",");
                String FROM = emailFrom.getText().toString();
                String SUBJECT = emailSubject.getText().toString();

                boolean valid = false;
                for (int counter = 0; counter < toArr.length; counter++) {

                    if (isValidEmail(toArr[counter])) {
                        valid = true;
                    } else {
                        valid = false;
                    }
                }
                if (valid && isValidEmail(FROM)) {
                    Mail m = new Mail("username",
                            "password");
                    m.setTo(toArr);
                    m.setFrom(FROM);
                    m.setSubject(SUBJECT);
                    m.setBody("<html><body bgcolor='#FFFFFF'>your html content</body></html>");
                    try {
                        if (m.send()) {
                            Toast.makeText(context,
                                    "A test Email was sent successfully.",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(context, "Email was not sent.",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Toast.makeText(context,
                                "There was a problem sending the email.",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                    finish();

                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Please enter a valid e-mails.",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
```

Use the above code to send the mail and Create a Class Mail in ur package like below:-

```
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Properties;
import javax.activation.CommandMap;
import javax.activation.DataHandler;
import javax.activation.DataSource;
import javax.activation.FileDataSource;
import javax.activation.MailcapCommandMap;
import javax.mail.BodyPart;
import javax.mail.Multipart;
import javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart;

/**
 * For using this class please add activation.jar, additionnal.jar and mail.jar
 * file to your build path
 * */
public class Mail extends javax.mail.Authenticator {
    private String _user;
    private String _pass;

    private String[] _to;
    private String _from;

    private String _port;
    private String _sport;

    private String _host;

    private String _subject;
    private String _body;

    private boolean _auth;

    private boolean _debuggable;

    private Multipart _multipart;

    public Mail() {
        _host = "smtp.gmail.com"; // default smtp server
        _port = "465"; // default smtp port
        _sport = "465"; // default socketfactory port

        _user = ""; // username
        _pass = ""; // password
        _from = ""; // email sent from
        _subject = ""; // email subject
        _body = ""; // email body

        _debuggable = false; // debug mode on or off - default off
        _auth = true; // smtp authentication - default on

        _multipart = new MimeMultipart();

        // There is something wrong with MailCap, javamail can not find a
        // handler for the multipart/mixed part, so this bit needs to be added.
        MailcapCommandMap mc = (MailcapCommandMap) CommandMap
                .getDefaultCommandMap();
        mc.addMailcap("text/html;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.text_html");
        mc.addMailcap("text/xml;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.text_xml");
        mc.addMailcap("text/plain;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.text_plain");
        mc.addMailcap("multipart/*;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.multipart_mixed");
        mc.addMailcap("message/rfc822;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.message_rfc822");
        CommandMap.setDefaultCommandMap(mc);
    }

    public Mail(String user, String pass) {
        this();

        _user = user;
        _pass = pass;
    }

    public boolean send() throws Exception {
        Properties props = _setProperties();

        if (!_user.equals("") && !_pass.equals("") && _to.length > 0
                && !_from.equals("") && !_subject.equals("")
                && !_body.equals("")) {
            Session session = Session.getInstance(props, this);

            MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage(session);

            msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(_from));

            InternetAddress[] addressTo = new InternetAddress[_to.length];
            for (int i = 0; i < _to.length; i++) {
                addressTo[i] = new InternetAddress(_to[i]);
            }
            msg.setRecipients(MimeMessage.RecipientType.TO, addressTo);

            msg.setSubject(_subject);
            msg.setSentDate(new Date());

            // setup message body
            BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
            messageBodyPart.setText(_body);
            _multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);

            // Put parts in message
            msg.setContent(_body, "text/html");

            // send email
            Transport.send(msg);

            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public void addAttachment(String filename) throws Exception {
        BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
        DataSource source = new FileDataSource(filename);
        messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));
        messageBodyPart.setFileName(filename);

        _multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);
    }

    @Override
    public PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
        return new PasswordAuthentication(_user, _pass);
    }

    private Properties _setProperties() {
        Properties props = new Properties();

        props.put("mail.smtp.host", _host);

        if (_debuggable) {
            props.put("mail.debug", "true");
        }

        if (_auth) {
            props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        }

        props.put("mail.smtp.port", _port);
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", _sport);
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class",
                "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "false");

        return props;
    }

    // the getters and setters
    public String getBody() {
        return _body;
    }

    public void setBody(String _body) {
        this._body = _body;
    }

    public void setTo(String[] toArr) {
        this._to = toArr;
    }

    public void setFrom(String string) {
        this._from = string;
    }

    public void setSubject(String string) {
        this._subject = string;
    }
    // more of the getters and setters …..
}
```

Answer (score 0):

See my answer in the below thread

[Fail to send mail using JavaMail API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11945602/fail-to-send-mail-using-javamail-api/11946542#11946542)

There i gave an working example to send mail using JavaMail

Also see my answer in this thread : [Connecting directly to GMAIL with android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11340023/connecting-directly-to-gmail-with-android/11340883#11340883)

Here you can download a working project, to test this